# How to intercept XmlHttpRequest with OWASP ZAP

Tags: zap

I'm using OWASP ZAP for intercepting request to a web application, OWASP WebGoat. My break point is quite simple: 'URL', 'contains', and 'http://localhost:8080/WebGoat/start.mvc#attack/76122667/400&from=ajax'. But it never catches any XMLHttpRequest with that URL while the Developer tool in browser does it well, ie can see that request.

I'm not sure if I am missing any further configuration. Please shed a light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the '#' and everything after it.
This is known as the 'fragment' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) and is not send by the browser, so its not present in the URL that ZAP sees.

Comment: FYI I've created a ZAP issue to warn about this: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/issues/4277

Comment: Thank you! Btw, the fragment part wasn't shown up in http request line, so that I was a bit confused at first time.